# How should I create a log off button in my menu bar that's rendered by a view helper?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, session-variables

I have a subnav bar in my module created from a view partial via a helper.

Here is the config in module.config.php:

```
'navigation' => array(
    'default' => array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Create',
            'route' => 'mymodule\Create',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'View',
            'route' => 'mymodule\view',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Search',
            'route' => 'mymodule\search',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Log Off',
            'route' => 'mymodule\logoff',
        ),
    ),
),
```

);

So here is my problem, I don't just want to redirect the user to the login page, I want to clear their session and THEN redirect them to the login page. I also don't want to have the login page just clear the session whenever a user navigates to it (in case they logged in and clicked the back button accidentally).

So what is the best way to handle this with my current config? I was thinking I could have my view helper that renders the partial set a flag in the session which the logon page would read and act accordingly- it would check for a "logoffButtonPress" flag in the session or something. But is it appropriate to do something like this in a view helper? Is this even possible in a view helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just have the button target a `logoutAction`?

I'm using `BjyAuthorise` and `ZfcUser` modules but the process of clearing the session and redirecting is the same.

**LoginController**

```
public function logoutAction()
{
    $this->authService->logout();

    $redirect = $this->params('redirect', false);

    if ($redirect) {
        return $this->redirect()->toUrl($redirect);
    }

    return $this->redirect()->toRoute(
        $this->config->getLogoutRedirectRoute()
    );
}
```

**AuthService**

```
public function logout()
{
    $adapter = $this->authService->getAdapter();

    $adapter->resetAdapters();
    $adapter->logoutAdapters();

    $this->authService->clearIdentity();
}
```

Comment: Ahhh so simple. Don't know why I couldn't figure this out, I already have a loginAction in my LoginController its only natural this would be taken care of by a logoutAction.

Comment: Hmm found a possible caveat, if I do it this way I'll need a logout template though won't I as the action corresponds to a template. Is there a clean way to get around this?

Comment: @user1028270 In my example the The `return $this->redirect()` short circuits the standard response (`ViewModel` etc) and performs a HTTP redirect, so there is no need for a view script.

Answer (score 0):

Like Alex says, that is the way to do that.

This code is correct

```
    array(
        'label' => 'Log Off',
        'route' => 'mymodule\logoff',
    ),
```

So, you need to set a logoff action to 'mymodule\logoff' route, clear the session and redirect the user to login or home or what you want.

On the login action you dont need to clear session.