# Can I have an action that doesn't load a template?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework-routing

I got an answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992189/how-should-i-create-a-log-off-button-in-my-menu-bar-thats-rendered-by-a-view-he), but now I have another concern\problem.

I have a subnav bar in my module created from a view partial via a helper.
Here is the config in module.config.php:

```
'navigation' => array(
    'default' => array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Search',
            'route' => 'mymodule\search',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Log Off',
            'route' => 'logout',
        ),
    ),
),
```

I have a LoginController with 2 actions: login and logout. After logging in I want the user to click the logout button, be redirected to the login page and have their session cleared.

Now if I have a login and logout action I need a template for each. This seems unnecessary for the logout action- I don't want another template to load for this action.

Here's my routing config:

```
'login' => array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
        'options' => array(
                'route' => '/login',
                'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Login',
                        'action' => 'login',
                ),
        ),
),
'logout' => array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
        'options' => array(
                'route' => '/login',
                'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Login',
                        'action' => 'logout',
                ),
        ),
),
```

Is there a correct way to have an action get called without loading a corresponding template?

Comment: Why would you want to log the user out as soon as they login?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can return a response object instead:

```
public function logoutAction()
{
    // do stuff

    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('login');
}
```

then you don't need a template.

Answer (score 3):

On zf2

```
public function Action(){
   $vm = new ViewModel();
   $vm->setTerminal(true);

   return $vm;
}
```

EDIT:::
In case that you want to return a custom response you can do:

```
public function Action(){
     return $this->getResponse()->setContent("Hello world!");
}
```

Comment: hmm maybe I'm doing something dumb here, but when I add that code to my logoutAction() I get this error: "**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "application/login/logout"; resolver could not resolve to a file' in **". Does this mean I'll still have to create a blank file?

Comment: Check the edit, you are preventing render the layout but you always need a view for the action, if you want to render something without layout and view check the edit of my answer.

Comment: Check tim answer that is what you need.